# How to make accessable input in resource columns in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need to have an opportunity to rename a resource name. I add a text input by `render()`, this works fine. But when I try to click into input, it is not possible and I do not know why. I just noticed, that `<body>` got new class `fc-unselectable`.

Is there a way how to prevent fullcalendar to let me access into inputs? But the rest of the calendar should be still editable.

I am using these settings and timeline-view.

```
plugins: [
  'interaction',
  'resourceTimeline'
],

editable: true,
eventResizableFromStart: true,
eventResourceEditable: true,
selectable: true,

resourceColumns: [{
  labelText: '',
  field: 'room',
  render: function(resource, el) {
    el.innerHTML = '<span class="fc-expander-space"><span class="fc-icon"></span></span><span class="fc-cell-text"><input type="text" value="' + el.innerText + '"></span>';
  }
}]
```